# Render custom block in template file

Tags: theming, 8

I want render my custom block in template file, but what I get is the block without going through the twig file.

```
theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) { 

    $block =  \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->createInstance('id_custom_block', array());
    $variables['custom_block'] = $block->build();

}
```

I Want render custom block, and different from a view block, this not work:

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('your_block_id');
$variables['block_output'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
->getViewBuilder('block')
->view($block);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you replace `your_block_id` with the actual ID name? Did you clear/flush the cache?

Comment: of course man !!